# The Matrix-style binary code, okay or BAD?

Tags: html, css, marquee

I needed some image-like illustration of something to do with IT, found an image of The Matrix characters and thought I might make that binary code and have it drop like it does in the movie.
So, should I use the code in my example (with hated MARQUEE tag (usually not a fan myself)), an animated GIF or are there better solutions other then not doing it at all ?

Are there any SEO problems when using MARQUEE (other then the effect it might have on visitors behavior on the website) ?

http://jsfiddle.net/fruLg/

CSS

```
#marq{ background-color: #000;
 height: auto;
 width: 27em;
}
#marqt{ font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.7em;
 color: #31B404;
}
#marqt td{ width: 0.7em;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="marq">
<table id="marqt">
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="2" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="2" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="2" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="2" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="2" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="2" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="2" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="2" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down"> 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0</marquee></td>
<td><marquee scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" direction="down">0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1</marquee></td>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea if this is a good or bad idea, performance wise, but it is the first time I have seen the marquee tag and laughed rather than sighed, so +1 for that. Having said that chrome shows a bit of a spike in cpu usage in top.

Comment: I think there are much "smoother" and current animation types like CCS3 transistions or canvas animation, which I'd both prefer, but this one surely still works in most browsers. See http://cssdeck.com/labs/the-matrix or http://upperdog.se/labs/matrix/ for really smooth examples using the stated techniques

Comment: @JohnBarça `<marqee>` is long time deprecated.

Comment: @Roko, yes, I am well aware of that. This is why I said it is a long time since I didn't sigh when seeing a marquee effect. It was out of date when I started web programming and, trust me, that is some time ago. I just though the effect was funny.

Comment: @JohnBarça :) I agree :) funny and a bit nostalgic reminding me on the good old days :) I just read your comment "`but it is the first time I have seen the marquee tag`" so I was a bit perplexed if that's really what you meant :D

Comment: It is the first time I have seen the marquee tag and laughed rather than sighed is what I said :-)

Comment: @JohnBarça I see now the deep meaning of your sentence! :) nice one!

Comment: Also, just because something is deprecated doesn't necessarily mean that it was for performance reasons, though in the case of the marquee tag vs css/canvas/javascript animations, you would have to assume that this was the case. Fortran is essentially deprecated, but not for performance reasons.

Comment: @Roko, yes, agreed :D

Comment: @JohnBarça I've found this and it's worth reading : http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3tutorials/a/marquee-in-css.htm

Comment: @thomasjaworski.com http://cssdeck.com/labs/the-matrix looks awesome and extremely lightweight. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use CSS3 transitions with keyframes to animate single `<span>` elements with your desired text. This would be the modern way. Otherwise an animated image should be good either.

`<marquee>` should never be used because it's no standard.

Edit: See http://jsfiddle.net/yEsw6/
Not perfect but it's the beginning. :)

Comment: +1 An example would make this answer even better, but otherwise an excellent first answer!

Comment: @LordTakkera Next time you should promise a `+1`. The answer (really) still lacks of quality, cause *'use CSS3'* is more appropriate as a comment, not as an answer. Any way doing it in pure CSS3 and *exactly* the way the OP's demo starts... seems quite a challenge to me (if not impossible) so I see no reason to +1 at all ;)

Comment: @KittMedia Thanks, Looks like THE solution; now I only have to play around for browser compatibility (and details)...